# Compare and rename duplicate files between two folders

Tags: command-line, scripts, checksums

For example:

I have 2 folders: `one` and `two`.

What is the command or script to do the following tasks:

- Check `sha256sum` of all files in `one` (and its subfolders). Then write their checksums in `one.txt`.
- Check `sha256sum` of all files in `two` (and its subfolders). Then write their paths and their checksums in `two.txt`.
- For each checksum in `one.txt`, find it in `two.txt`. If that checksum exists in `two.txt`, then rename the file in `two` with that checksum. (`fullfilename` becomes `fullfilename.dupdupdup`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you don't have newlines in the file names:

```bsh
grep \
-f <(find one -type f -exec sha256sum {} + | awk '{print $1}') \
<(find two -type f -not -name "*.dupdupdup" -exec sha256sum {} +) \
| cut -c 67- \
| xargs -I{} mv {} {}.dupdupdup
```